# How to give timeout for process in Java and Android for ReadUnsignedByte()

Tags: android, exception, timeout

I have the following code and I use ReadUnsignedByte() function but hangs and doesn't return anything which cause hanging the application. I used try catch but there is no response, so what shall I do in this case ?

```
private int getEndOfSeqeunce(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws TimeoutException {
    int seqIndex = 0;
    byte c = -99;
    for(int i=0; i < FRAME_MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        Log.v("DataInputStream", ""+in);
        try {
            c = (byte) in.readUnsignedByte(); // Stuck here ... No response at this line which hangs the Android application.
            Log.v("C ::::::::UNSIGNE::readUnsignedByte::::::::", ""+c);
            if(c == sequence[seqIndex]) {
                seqIndex++;
                if(seqIndex == sequence.length) return i + 1;
            } else seqIndex = 0;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            i = FRAME_MAX_LENGTH;
            Activity ac = (Activity) cox;   
            }

    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: No response, it doesn't print anything, I tried to log it but it didn't reach the next line.

Comment: what is that datainputstream is wrapping? Log.v("DataInputStream", ""+in); don't you get a print for that?

Comment: To make sure that you don't hang your application: Use AsyncTask :)

Comment: I used AsyncTask but it also hangs the UI because I wait for a result from the AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a blocking call and you can't set a timeout, it has to either return data or fail with an exception. If you are reading from a socket, it will block until the read timeout is reached (if set). You might want to run this in a separate thread in order to not hang the UI, but it will still block. If this is for a communication protocol, maybe you have a problem some where and are expecting data that is not being sent.